# NSOperationQueue operations and operationsCount deprecated. How to cancel operations of a specific class?

Tags: nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

This documentation says that `operations` is deprecated with no hint of a replacement function:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1415168-operations?language=objc

Xcode lists a possible replacement as `addBarrierBlock:` but with no documentation.

I have a dozen operations of class `RenderOperation` and a single operation of class `RenderCompleteOperation` that is dependent on all the `RenderOperation` objects.

My problem is that if I call `cancelAllOperations`, I still need my single `RenderCompleteOperation` to run - and if it is still pending completion of its dependencies, than its `main` method will never run.

So I need a way to cancel just the `RenderOperation` objects and can't see how to do this without calling `operations`.

Answer (score 1):

An operation can be dependant on an operation in a different queue so you can put your final operation on a separate queue to the worker operations and use `cancelAllOperations` on the worker queue.

Another option is to override the final operation's `cancel` function to do nothing and set `executing` and `finished` manually when it finishes its task.

A third option is to keep an array of your worker operations and cancel each of them yourself in a loop (which is all `cancelAllOperations` does anyway)

Comment: Where is it specifically documented that a dependency can be made to an operation in a different queue? This question seems to indicate that isn't supported:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576930/nsoperation-with-dependency-on-another-operation-on-a-different-queue-does-not-s

Comment: I've never tried dependencies between two queues but I've heard it in WWDC sessions. Here's one place it's mentioned: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/?time=690

Comment: The question you link to doesn't say it isn't supported, just that they couldn't get it working. Try it yourself and see. Personally I think an array with operations to be cancelled is less hassle (except maybe the hassle of making sure to clean up properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cancel` on all the dependencies of your `RenderCompleteOperation`:

```
renderCompleteOperation.dependencies.forEach { $0.cancel() }
```

It will then execute immediately.

Comment: This does work, but it requires that I keep a reference to the completion operation. Not a terrible problem, but not quite as nice as some way to do it using only the queue.